# Flask: Reach app from subfolders

Tags: python, import

I have a hierarchy like this

```
Project/
|-- app/
|-- folder1/
|   |-- code1.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.py
```

I am trying from code1.py to reach my "app" Flask variable defined such as 
app = Flask(`__name__`) in `__init__.py` located in app folder

I can't seem to import my app variable, I have tried the following-

```
from Project.app import app
from .. import app
from ..app import app
from ...app import app
```

When I tried the `Project.app import app` I get `import issues trying to import code1` (which contains a blueprint I am registering in `__init__.py` where app is defined.

Comment: This isn't really a Flask problem, you could make the same example without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose that your code runs within the Project folder. That means that the current module directory is 'Project'. That means you can access all subfolders as long as they are treated as modules(the have a __init__.py file).

```
Project/
|-- run.py <
|-- app/
|-- folder1/
|   |-- code1.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.py
```

In run.py all of the following are valid

```
import folder1
import .
from folder1 import code1
from folder1.code1 import <submodule>
```

If your app is in folder1/__init__.py

```
from folder1 import app
```